# bash - sed query to edit yaml file

Tags: bash, vim, sed

I have a config.yaml file which contains among other values the following list of kafka brokers which I want to remove from the config using a bash script.

```
kafka.brokers:
    - "node003"
    - "node004"
```

I am doing this currently by invoking **vi** from inside the script using the command:

```
vi $CONF_BENCHMARK/config.yaml -c ":%s/kafka.brokers:\(\n\s*-\s".*"\)*/kafka.brokers:/g" -c ':wq!'
```

I understand that **sed** is a more appropriate tool to accomplish the same task but when I try to translate the above regex to **sed**, it does not work.

```
sed -i -e "s/kafka.brokers:\(\n\s*-\s".*"\)*/kafka.brokers:/g" $CONF_BENCHMARK/config.yaml
```

I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: `sed is a more appropriate tool` -> No, a YAML parser is a more appropriate tool :-) YAML is pretty complex, and not at all suited to be modified ad-hoc with shells scripts and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other have pointed out, you will need to be explicit to get sed working with multiply lines.

The real answer is to use [AWK a beautiful answer is provided by karakfa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41214802/887539). But for the educational purpose I will provide an sed answer:

```
sed  '
  /kafka.brokers/ {
    :a
    $be
    N
    /\n[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]"[^\n]*"[^\n]*$/ba
    s/\n.*\(\n\)/\1/
    P;D
    :e
    s/\n.*//
  }
' input
```

Basically sed will keep append lines to the pattern space from when `kafka.brokers` up until `\n[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]"[^\n]*"[^\n]*$` is not matches.

This will leave the pattern space with one trailing line it in, i.e:

```
kafka.brokers:\n    - "node003"\n    - "node004"\nother stuff$
```

Replacing everything `\n.*\(\n\)` with a newline leaves the following pattern space:

```
kafka.brokers:\nother stuff$
```

`P;D` will print the first line from the pattern space and then restart the cycle with the remaning pattern space. Making the input support:

```
kafka.brokers:
    - "node003"
    - "node004"
kafka.brokers:
    - "node005"
more_input
```

Answer (score 6):

`awk` to the rescue!

`sed` is line based, this should work...

```
$ awk 's{if(/\s*-\s*"[^"]*"/) next; else s=0} /kafka.brokers:/{s=1}1' file
```

**Explanation**

> `if(/\s*-\s*"[^"]*"/) next`  if pattern matches skip to next line
>   `s{if(/\s...` check pattern if only s is set
>   `/kafka.brokers:/{s=1}` when header seen set s
>   `1` shorthand for print lines (if not skipped)
>   `s{... else s=0}` if s was set but pattern not found, reset s

Comment: Can you please explain how this works ? I might have to modify it a bit before I can use it.

Comment: Btw I tried your solution on the example provided above and it does not work.

Comment: it doesn't work is not very descriptive... Nothing printed? Nothing filtered? Deleted the input file?

Comment: It printed the contents as it is i.e it did not make any changes.

Comment: [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44984391/52499) for why `1` prints the line.

Answer (score 1):

Your Vim pattern matches across multiple lines, but sed works line-by-line. (That is, it first tries to match your pattern against `kafka.brokers:` and fails, then it tries to match `- "node003"`, and so on.) Your instinct to use something other than Vim was right, but sed probably isn't the best tool for the job here.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26290) addresses the problem of matching multi-line patterns with sed in more detail.

My personal recommendation would be to use a scripting language like Python or Perl to deal with complicated pattern-matching. You can run a Python command with `python -c <command>`, for instance, just like you did with Vim, or you could write a small Python script that you call from your Bash script. It's a little more complicated than a sed one-liner, but it will probably save you a lot of debugging and make your script easier to maintain and modify.

Comment: I tried perl as `perl -pi -e "s/kafka.brokers:\(\n\s*-\s".*"\)*/kafka.brokers:/g" config.yaml` but that does not seem to work either. I hope python works for me.

Comment: @andlrc I am trying to replace in-place in the file `config.yaml` as my code in the comment above shows. Running your suggestion results `Can't open perl script "s/kafka....": No such file or directory`

Comment: @HaseebJaved `perl -p0e '...'` will slurp the whole file at one go. Use `-pi -0e` to do inplace edit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) instead of `sed` or `awk`. Deleting the key `kafka.brokers` then becomes as simple as:

```
yq d $CONF_BENCHMARK/config.yaml '"kafka.brokers"'
```

The following snippet demonstrates the `yq` delete feature:

```
cat <<EOF | yq d - '"kafka.brokers"'    
some:
  path: value
kafka.brokers:
  - "node003"
  - "node004"
EOF
```

... and results in the output

```
some:
  path: value
```