# Tokenize a string with awk in bash script

Tags: bash

I want to read lines of a file line by line, tokinize every line and do some processings. The file structure and script look like

```
[root@localhost:~] cat vms.txt
mahmood May 24
[root@localhost:~] cat power_offs2.sh
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=/vms.txt
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line" | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[1],a[2],a[3]}'
    NAME=a[1]
    NEW_MONTH=a[2]
    NEW_DAY=a[3]
    echo $NAME "-" $NEW_MONTH "-" $NEW_DAY
done < $INPUT
```

The output however is

```
[root@localhost:~] sh /power_offs2.sh
mahmood May 24
a[1] - a[2] - a[3]
```

It seems that array is defined in the awk scope. How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you clarify expected output. The input file is space delimited, but the `awk` is splitting on vertical bar ('|'). Which one you want ?

Comment: My fault... There are spaces between words and '|' is wrong. Even if I change that to `$0,a," "`, I don't see the words in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick fix:

```
NAME=$(awk '{print $1}' vms.txt)
NEW_MONTH=$(awk '{print $2}' vms.txt)
NEW_DAY=$(awk '{print $3}' vms.txt)
echo $NAME "-" $NEW_MONTH "-" $NEW_DAY
```

Comment: OK I fixed it with `NAME=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`` and so on in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

From the input, looks like the text is space delimited. You can use bash `read` for that

```
while read name month dd ; do
    printf '%s-%s-%s\n' "$name" "$month" "$dd"
done < $INPUT
```

Output:

```
mahmood-May-24
```

Comment: You missed the input file variable. No?

Comment: @mahmood, Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -v OFS="-" '{$1=$1}1' vms.txt
mahmood-May-24
```

- `-v OFS="-"` sets the output field separator to `-` (default is a space character)
- `$1=$1` rebuilds the record according to the modified output field separator `OFS`.
  This is described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html) (bottom of the page) in the GNU Awk manual.
- `1` is a pattern without an action and evaluates to **true**. This is a common shorthand to trigger the default action to print the current record (same as `{print}` or `{print $0}`, see [Why does “1” in awk print the current line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262869/why-does-1-in-awk-print-the-current-line)).

Answer (score 0):

As the OP's determined, the array (`a[]`) has scope within the `awk` call and therefore the array cannot be referenced by the calling process.

Assumptions:

- input data is delimited by white space
- we're only dealing with a single line of input
- the parsed values need to be accessible by the parent script

We can eliminate the need for `awk`, as well as any subprocessing (eg, `echo | awk`, `$(awk ...)`) and use a simple `read` command:

```
$ cat vms.txt
mahmood May 24

$ read -r NAME NEW_MONTH NEW_DAY < vms.txt

$ echo $NAME "-" $NEW_MONTH "-" $NEW_DAY
mahmood - May - 24
```

---

Based on a comment by the OP about using `$line`, I'll remove the assumption that we're only dealing with a single line of interest in `vms.txt` ...

Using the same method as above but replacing `vms.txt` as input with `$line` as input (in the form of a 'here' string):

```
$ line='mahmood May 24'

$ read -r NAME NEW_MONTH NEW_DAY <<< "${line}"

$ echo $NAME "-" $NEW_MONTH "-" $NEW_DAY
mahmood - May - 24
```

Again, this should eliminate subprocessing calls and be a bit faster if dealing with a large volume of `$line`s.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `tr ' ' '-' <vms.txt`

Bash-only if you want to tokenise into an array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=' ' read -r -d '' -a array <vms.txt
IFS='-'
echo "${array[*]}"
IFS="$_OIFS"
```

See: [How can I join elements of an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841619/7939871)